# Windows 7 desktop does not automatically refresh

Tags: windows-7, desktop

I am using Windows 7.

If I delete something from the desktop, then the icon remains there.

I have to hit F5 or right-click->Refresh to make the desktop refresh.  After the refresh, the icon disappears.

Any suggestions?

Comment: _(Can't post as answer due rep)_ Go to: **(Explorer) Folder Options > Search tab** and check or uncheck some of the options. Pretty stupid bug.

Answer (score 6):

I finally found the answer to this...

Open **regedit** and search for `dontrefresh`.

You should find a value that has `dontrefresh` set to `1`. Change this value to `0` and your problem should be solved.

I found the value under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{BDEADE7F-C265-11D0-BCED-00A0C90AB50F}\Instance`

I confirmed the fix on my laptop. No more pressing F5 after I make a new folder or move a file to my desktop!

Comment: Unfortunately, `dontrefresh` does not exist in my registry (according to the commens [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/desktop-does-not-refresh-automatically-windows), neither does on many other computers). I could obviously create it, but hard to to tell under what path it should be made.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) fix:

```
While 1
{
    IfWinExist Confirm File Delete ahk_class #32770
    {
        WinWaitClose, Confirm File Delete ahk_class #32770
        ControlSend,,{F5},ahk_class Progman
    }
    Sleep 1
}
```

**Explaination:**

If the confirm file delete dialog is open, wait until it's closed then send <kbd>F5</kbd> to the desktop. I know this will always refresh the desktop even if the file wasn't deleted from the desktop, but it doesn't hurt anything really.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "$Del::" , as you send {Del} itself in the script?

Comment: last approach was bad anyways, changed it all around.

Comment: Shouldn't that have a `While, 1` in there, in case the OP wants to delete more than one file? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by removing the CPU clock from the side bar, this tool caused the problem and also didn't allow the machine to shut down properly.

If that is not the case, think about an application that you have installed recently that might cause this fault and remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I have the sidebar completely turned off.

Comment: Just about any 3rd party utility or extension can cause this in the same manner, so this is a good answer to consider, even if you don't have this specific utility.

Answer (score 0):

The cause on my PC was a "Network Location" that was pointing to a server that was turned off.

When I deleted that Network Location, all my icons started refreshing normally.

Here's a screenshot to show what I mean by Network Location:

[image]

This solution was originally found in a [comment by Emin Guzel](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/desktop-does-not-refresh-automatically-windows#comment-2579112117) after HOURS of searching and experimenting with solutions.