# When deleting files from the Desktop folder on Win10, why do I need to refresh the Desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, gui, user-interface

Running Win10 (V 1511 b 10586.589)...

When I delete files from File Explorer > Desktop, the files remain on my desktop. If I try to open them from the actual Desktop (and not the folder in Explorer), an error message pops up saying the file has been removed. I need to manually right click on the root window and do a "Refresh". It seems very odd to me that major state changes on the primary UI don't trigger a UI refresh.

This equal parts gripe and genuine curiosity. I'd like to know if there is a programmatic reason behind this. Is it because Win10 is multi-platform and is associated with some weird table<>laptop UX conflict? Is it too computationally expensive to do a refresh? Might it trigger a long-latency IO (disk or network), so to hide the latency they associate it with a user-initiated action? Or is it a gross oversight?

This is not a duplicate of the Win7 question ([Windows 7 desktop does not automatically refresh](https://superuser.com/questions/69219/windows-7-desktop-does-not-automatically-refresh)) because I want to know WHY this is the case. I already know how to fix it. I'd like to know if there is an underlying strategy for this odd UI behavior, specifically from windows super-users.

Comment: "This is not a duplicate of the Win7 question" - Yes; It actually is.  The desktop is suppose to refresh, if it doesn't, then implement the fix describe in the answer to the duplicate question (which still applies to Windows 10).  The answers to ALL your sub-questions is simply: **No**;  You have came up with the incorrect conclusions, your desktop should refresh, the fact it isn't means its something unique about your configuration.

Comment: A fresh Windows installation won't get this problem so this likely happens after installing some certain programmes that affect performance inside Windows explorer. Probably you should check a list of your installed programmes

Comment: You might be able to resolve the configuration problem by updating your installation to the current 14393 build of Windows 10.